# Firing event in WCF (4.5) host

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-4

I am trying to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302932/firing-event-in-wcf-host) to work in the latest version of WCF.

The problem is that `BatServ` does not show up for me to use from the service reference that was added.  Only `IBatServ` does.  is this because of the latest version of WCF or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to fire an event at the host *from the client side* - and you can't do it directly (the link you pointed out is an event fired at the host *from the server side*). The host is potentially on a different computer than the client, so there's no direct way for the latter to access the former. What you can do is to have an operation on the server which the client can call, and that operation can fire the event at the host.